# Define no-sources files for Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is it possible to specify no-sources files that should not trigger the Gitlab CI?

When I make changes in `README.md`, the pipeline triggers, thought that file is only the documentation inside the gitlab and is not packaged in anz output artifact.

Comment: Typically you'd put `[skip ci]` in the commit message if you don't want a commit to trigger a build, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#skip-pipeline

Comment: You can list the globs paths that should trigger the ci stage in a `only: changes:` stanza => https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges.

Comment: @Zeitounator it look what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can control when each of your jobs is added to a running pipeline using the `only`, `except`, or `rules` keywords. The easiest way to prevent jobs from running when only the README is changed is with `except`:

```
build_job:
  stage: build
  except:
    changes:
      - README.md
```

With this job syntax, if the only file that changes in a push is `README.md`, this job will not run. Unfortunately you can only set these rules at a job level, not the pipeline level so you'd have to put this in each of your jobs to prevent them all from running.